# How to force java object to instantiate it's instance variables in specific order?

Tags: java, oop, instance-variables

Having a class:

```
class Test {

  Object1 object1;
  Object2 object2;

  void setObject2 (Object2 newObject) {
    if (object1.someMethod()) {
      this.object2 = newObject;
    } else {
      someOtherMethod();
    }
  }
}
```

How can I force object instantiation that `object1` must be instantiate before `object2`?

For now I can think to solve it

1.by making constructor with `Object2` as parameter and instantiate it there

```
Test(Object1 object1) {
  this.object1 = object1;
}
```

2.by throwing exception from the method which try to set `object2`

```
void setObject2 (Object newObject) {
  if (object1 == null) {
    throw new Exception();
  }
  ...
```

**Is there any other, more appropriate way to achieve it?**

The reason I need it is that I have to create new advertisement campaign `Test` for a region `object1` to advertise some of the region's sites `object2`. Before I can add site to campaign I want to check if the site belongs to the region.

Comment: Can I ask you what is you purpose?

Comment: @acornagl are you asking me?

Comment: @ItamarGreen no, I'm sorry I was asking to Marcin but something went wrong with the `@`

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: @ItamarGreen I construct the question in generic (general) way, its not a working code.

Comment: @acornagl I have to create new advertisement campaign for a region to advertise some of the region's sites. Before I can add site to campaign I want to check if the site belongs to the region.

Comment: @MarcinKruglik I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cleaner way design-wise can be to use the Builder-pattern. This way you can setup and create your objects only in correct ways instead of getting exceptions at runtime.

The programmer doesn't need to read documentation or error messages to find out what he needs to do, since the API does the "guiding" itself.

Comment: Actually, I use Builder-pattern in my real code. I tried to make my question general, not bind to specific case. Even tho I use builder, I need to use some algorithm to check if instance variables are instantiated in correct order.

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the initialization of `object2` so that it can only be instanciated if `object` has been.

```
public void setObject2 (Object2 newObject) {
    if(object1 == null){ 
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }else{
        this.object2 = newObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Above is correct, additionally the method can throw java.lang.IllegalStateException, so the person working on the class knows something has been messed up. *IllegalStateException: Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.*

Comment: This is a bad idea, because the caller has no way of knowing that the call to the setter had no effect.

Comment: @Bohemian fixing it. implementing srinath's idea

Comment: @ItamarGreen or maybe you can make it return a boolean value to indicate if the operation ended successfully.

Comment: @aleb2000 no need, if the user receives an exception, they know what went wrong

Comment: This answer is exactly what I proposed as 2nd solution in my question. I've used there generic "Exception", but yes, in my code I'm using IllegalStateException for this matter. So it doesn't answer my question, if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: I don't know, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @MarcinKruglik well it received upvotes, and I tested it and it works... (tested with very simple case)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Initializing the variables to appropriate state SHOULD be done using constructors, you can actually create a `Test class constructor` to achieve the same as shown below:

```
public Test(Object1 obj1, Object2 obj2) {
    //if objects are null throw an error
    if(obj1 == null) {
       throw IllegalStateException("Invalid Object1 passed");
    } else {
      this.obj1 = obj1;
     //check someMethod() returns true and then set object2
     if (obj1.someMethod()) {
      this.obj2 = obj2;
     } else {
       //obj1.someMethod() is false, call someOtherMethod()
       someOtherMethod();
    }
  }
```

It is best practice to throw `Exception` (like above) from the constructor if it's mandatory variables state is not initialized properly so that the object will not be in inconsistent state after it's creation.

Comment: If use your constructor, then exception will be thrown all time (obj1 is always null)

Comment: Why obj1 is always null ?

Comment: Sorry I thought you refer to `this.obj1`.